# htaccess to block file but not dir

Tags: .htaccess

I have an htaccess problem with it blocking my directory because of the filesmatch flag.
I'm trying to block log files, but on my site also maintain a blog.
What happens is that if people come to site.com/blog they get a 403 error vs site.com/blog/ works just fine.  Also some other functions within the blog fail as well because of this error.
I guess i'm not sure if the filesmatch is correct/working properly or how to fix this.  htaccess files have never been my friend :p

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

# Prevent Directoy listing 
Options -Indexes

# Prevent Direct Access to files
 <FilesMatch ".(tpl|log|ini)">
 Order allow,deny
 Deny from all
 </FilesMatch>

# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your `.` in the `<FilesMatch>` container. It expects a regular expression and the `.` character means *"any character that isn't a newline"*.

```
 <FilesMatch "\.(tpl|log|ini)">
   Order allow,deny
   Deny from all
 </FilesMatch>
```

Comment: @user2238714 [Works fine for me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6exbO.png). Are you sure you're not getting a 403 for some other reason?

Comment: actually that may not be entirely true..when i take the "log" out, the url gets the trailing slash appended and consequently works.  order of operations?

Comment: ok well i got it working and i think the escaping was part of it.  I got a different snippet and it works although i dont really understand it...but then again, that's why i was here to begin with haha.  This is supposed to be a better/more secure way from what im told 
`<FilesMatch "(?i)((\.tpl|\.ini|\.log|(?<!robots)\.txt))">`
THanks for the help Jon!